# C# Collision Determine a graphical shape with an object on the form

Tags: c#

[image]

I want to determine collision between the shape and the label, but I can't, I searched all the event of label and I've got nothing, what should i do for that ?

Comment: You might see [How to do c# collision detection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3195540/2026740)

Comment: _"I searched all the event of label"_ - Your green circle doesn't really "exist", it's drawn on a much larger control - there's nothing there for the label to collide with, you'll need to do some maths yourself to work out if they're colliding, rather than relying on built-in events.